# how to skip test step in test case in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

[plese click to see screen short image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va94T.png)

this popup (comment code) is avalible some time
but i don't want to comment code every time when pop up not avalible
how to skip this step when pop up not avalible
plese help me find the way to exit this problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Robot Framework 4.0 introduced built-in IF/ELSE support. You can skip test steps based on a condition.

Answer (score 1):

The "Run keyword and Ignore Error" will run every time and check element is visible and on visible, it will execute the Handle_popup

Add these two line in your test case and add the below keyword in your keywords section.

```
${PopupVisible}=     Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Wait_20s_And_Ensure_Visibilty           ${XPATH_CLOSE_POPUP_EXPIRE}
Run Keyword If    "${PopupVisible}[0]" == "PASS"    Handle_Popup    ${XPATH_CLOSE_POPUP}


*** Keywords ***
Wait_20s_And_Ensure_Visibilty
    [Arguments]    ${Element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${Element}    timeout=20s
    Capture Page Screenshot

Handle_Popup    
    #Here add your commented code which you shown in image
```